# Is there a driver for a NVIDIA GeForce GT525M?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus

I'm planning to buy a new laptop : http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-l502x/pd?oc=dndodq1&model_id=xps-l502x

In this laptop there is a 1024MB NVIDIA® GeForce® GT525M video card.

But when i looked on the nvidia site to download drivers they don't have any linux drivers for this card... http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us

Will i be able to use this video card in ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laptop with Nvidia Optimus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/laptop-with-nvidia-optimus)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely but check here to make sure.
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog

Comment: please recheck your direction. NVIDIA Optimus is **not** supported in linux yet. Please see my answer for clarity or check http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/laptop-with-nvidia-optimus/37122#37122 for details.

Comment: @nik Thanks for the correction. Feel free to correct me any time you think I'm. Chances are I probably am.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no support for the Optimus based NVIDIA graphics in linux/ Ubuntu yet**.
If you decide to go for an Optimus system laptop you are likely to be working with your integrated Intel graphics while in Ubuntu.

<sub>[been there, done that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/laptop-with-nvidia-optimus/37122#37122) -- I write this from a L502x 525M XPS running Natty :-)</sub>

Comment: There is now relatively good support for using both card simultaneously, Intel for desktop and Nvidia for performance applications with bumblebee: https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Answer (score 1):

The support for Nvidia Optimus under Linux has improved a bit recently. Have a look at:
http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Sadly, for this Dell laptop, we still haven't found out a way to switch off the card...

Answer (score 1):

The diriver is now supported in Nvidia Website.

tey, I advice you to use bumblebee project that supports OPTIMUS for the Dell XPS L502X.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-295.49-driver.html

- I have 540M. I use Bumblebee for switching 540M*

Answer (score 0):

I have look here ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/270.30/README/supportedchips.html  where you can see all the supported videocards for the latest beta driver but the GT525M isn't listed.

We i be able to use this card with another driver?

Comment: welcome to Ask Ubuntu, the way this site works is you update your original question with this information so it doesn't get lost. As you update it people will adjust their answers accordingly. After you add this to your question feel free to delete this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the above solution by G Simpson works on my Samsung RC512 with NVIDIA GeForce GT525M.  Thank you so much, I was almost ready to buy a new laptop.  All 3D acceleration works!  Desktop, Quake, Unreal, etc.

Bumblebee FTW

Did a `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

then a `sudo apt-get update`

then a `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

After removing all other Nvidia software BTW.